# Does there exist such holomorphic bijection?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $A=\{z\in\mathbb{C} \mid \mathrm{Re}(z)>0\}$ and $B=\{z\in\mathbb{C} \mid 0<\mathrm{Re}(z)<1\}$. Is there a holomorphic bijection $f:A\rightarrow B$?

Comment: @vitamind I think you misunderstood my question. Your example is not bijective. Please undo your downvote if you did it.

Comment: This question may be closed unless you tell us more. What are your ideas? Surely you've been studying material related to this question. What material in the last 10 pages of your book could be useful? Please tell us, we're not here to do your homework.

Comment: @zhw My question is simple enough to be stated in one sentence as it is and I can't give any useful material as I came up with it on my own after reading someone else's homework. Adding a list of my unfortunate attempts won't help those who can solve it in a second and help me. If you are not that person then don't be rude and simply ignore my question.

Comment: Exercises of this type are often of the variety of putting together mapping properties of a known toolbox of functions. There is a general theorem (the Riemann mapping theorem) which provides background assurance that such a mapping exists. Finding formulas is a question of piecing together mapping properties of functions you "know." You can find textbooks cataloging explicit formulas for such maps in all kinds of domains. Or you could in theory if libraries were open (as they aren't where I live). The main thing I miss about libraries is showing up, looking around, and finding this stuff.

Comment: @leslietownes Thank you very much! We didn't study this yet on my university, so you gave me some great insight in what I might learn in future. Honestly, messing with such a catalog sounds fun, I hope my university has one :)

Comment: @donaastor often the books will have "conformal mapping" or something similar in the title instead of "holomorphic bijection" but it's frequently the same thing. Also if math and applied sciences have different libraries go to the applied sciences library too because people use them to model fluid flows and heat transfer and other things. A bunch of simple geometries (including e.g. polygons) are catalogued and you can pull them right out of the box. Although the formulas do get ugly very fast.

Comment: @leslietownes Thank you so much! I don't think I will explicitly need all that, but it sounds fun to check out. Now I know where exactly to look for and not wander.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Try a constant multiple of an appropriate branch of $\log$.

Comment: Thanks! I've got it. I thought that there isn't such function.

Comment: @donaastor for simply connected domains that are not all of $\mathbb{C}$ you have https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem as assurance. When in doubt try to look up or find something mapping the thing you have into the disc, and then another thing mapping the disc into the thing you want.